# Mysql query code improvement

Tags: mysql

I am fairly new to coding and through my own interest I am attempting to create a database system for work and very much learning as I go along.

I have a database query which is designed to show recent results where `Sample Name`, `Tank Name` and `Customer` match. These are from three different but related tables.

I have come up with the following query. **This Query Works** but for my own education am I working along the right lines or is there a better way of approaching this problem (this looks very untidy and hard to read to my mind)?

```
SELECT 
  `t_workorders`.`Work Order`,
  `t_workorders`.`Date Sampled`,
  `Result`,
  `t_test_units`.`Unit` 
FROM
  `t_sampletests` 
  RIGHT JOIN `t_samples` 
    ON `Sample` = `pk_Sample` 
  RIGHT JOIN `t_workorders` 
    ON `t_samples`.`Work Order` = `t_workorders`.`Work Order` 
  LEFT JOIN `t_test_units` 
    ON `t_sampletests`.`Unit` = `t_test_units`.`pk_Unit` 
WHERE `t_sampletests`.`Test` = 
  (SELECT 
    `Test` 
  FROM
    `t_sampletests` 
  WHERE `pk_SampleTest` = $ testID) 
  AND `t_Samples`.`Sample Name` = 
  (SELECT 
    `Sample Name` 
  FROM
    `t_sampletests` 
    LEFT JOIN `t_Samples` 
      ON `Sample` = `pk_Sample` 
  WHERE `pk_SampleTest` = $ testID) 
  AND `t_Samples`.`Tank` = 
  (SELECT 
    `Tank` 
  FROM
    `t_sampletests` 
    LEFT JOIN `t_Samples` 
      ON `Sample` = `pk_Sample` 
  WHERE `pk_SampleTest` = $ testID) 
  AND `t_workorders`.`Customer` = 
  (SELECT 
    `Customer` 
  FROM
    `t_sampletests` 
    LEFT JOIN `t_Samples` 
      ON `Sample` = `pk_Sample` 
    LEFT JOIN `t_workorders` 
      ON `t_Samples`.`Work Order` = `t_workorders`.`Work Order` 
  WHERE `pk_SampleTest` = $ testID) 
  AND `t_workorders`.`Work Order` <> 
  (SELECT 
    `t_workorders`.`Work Order` 
  FROM
    `t_sampletests` 
    LEFT JOIN `t_Samples` 
      ON `Sample` = `pk_Sample` 
    LEFT JOIN `t_workorders` 
      ON `t_Samples`.`Work Order` = `t_workorders`.`Work Order` 
  WHERE `pk_SampleTest` = $ testID) 
ORDER BY `t_workorders`.`Work Order` DESC 
LIMIT 15
```

Any suggestions of alternative or more suitable approaches would be greatly appreciated.

Many Thanks

Comment: any problem to this query?

Comment: What about trying to format it so that it can be read easily. Use new lines and increment..?

Comment: i suggest do not use like this right join 

`t_workorders.. this will include all fields from t_workorders

Comment: use the field you only need..not all

Comment: Thanks reds, I did not realize that right-join 't_workorders` would include all fields. I had assumed that only the fields following the SELECT would be included and that the join only provided a link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO, using new lines and increments will help you read and structure the query and allow you to have a quick overview of what it does.

I also try to be consistent when using SQL keywords and write them in upper case.

```
SELECT `t_workorders`.`Work Order`, `t_workorders`.`Date Sampled`, `Result`,`t_test_units`.`Unit`
FROM `t_sampletests`
RIGHT JOIN `t_samples` ON `Sample` = `pk_Sample` 
RIGHT JOIN `t_workorders` ON `t_samples`.`Work Order` = `t_workorders`.`Work Order`
LEFT JOIN `t_test_units`ON `t_sampletests`.`Unit` = `t_test_units`.`pk_Unit`
WHERE `t_sampletests`.`Test` = (
    SELECT `Test` FROM `t_sampletests` WHERE `pk_SampleTest` = $testID
  )
  AND `t_Samples`.`Sample Name` = (
    SELECT `Sample Name`
    FROM `t_sampletests`
    LEFT JOIN `t_Samples` ON `Sample` = `pk_Sample` WHERE `pk_SampleTest` = $testID
  )
  AND `t_Samples`.`Tank` = (
    SELECT `Tank`
    FROM `t_sampletests`
    LEFT JOIN `t_Samples` ON `Sample` = `pk_Sample` WHERE `pk_SampleTest` = $testID
  )
  AND `t_workorders`.`Customer`= (
    SELECT `Customer`
    FROM `t_sampletests`
    LEFT JOIN `t_Samples` ON `Sample` = `pk_Sample`
    LEFT JOIN `t_workorders` ON `t_Samples`.`Work Order` = `t_workorders`.`Work Order`
    WHERE `pk_SampleTest` = $testID
  )
  AND `t_workorders`.`Work Order` <> (
    SELECT `t_workorders`.`Work Order`
    FROM `t_sampletests`
    LEFT JOIN `t_Samples` ON `Sample` = `pk_Sample`
    LEFT JOIN `t_workorders` ON `t_Samples`.`Work Order` = `t_workorders`.`Work Order` 
    WHERE `pk_SampleTest` = $testID
  )
ORDER BY `t_workorders`.`Work Order`
DESC LIMIT 15;
```

(and don't forget the `;` at then end of your query)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
select feild1, field2 from
(select feild1, field2 from table1)as a

left join

select field1, desc from table2) as b
on a.field1 = b.field1
```

this will optimized your query

Avoid selecting all fields in a table that you are not using it.. select only fields you want to display to optimized